# git rm command unexpectedly staged the file instead of removing it

Tags: git

I removed test.txt file with this command:

`git rm test.txt`

then git status result was as:

[image]

Then I tried this command:

`git reset head test.txt`

to unstage changes and the result:

[image]

and finally I tried to remove the txt file with this command:

`git rm test.txt`

but the command unexpectedly **staged **the file instead of **removing **it:

[image]

Could you please explain misunderstanding with this command?

Comment: The file is deleted since your first command, after you just change the state between staged or no staged. Why do you say the file is not removed ?

Comment: How could git remove the file if it didn’t stage the deletion?

Comment: just check with `ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rm test.txt` not only records the `test.txt` deletion in the Git index, but also removes it from your working tree (local disk).

Unstaging the deletion still leaves the `text.txt` deleted on disk.
A new `git rm` simply re-stage the deletion.

If you had done a [`git rm --cached test.txt`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached), then unstaging the deletion would have left a clean git status.